# Terminal won't open after brew upgrade (dyld library not loaded)

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I ran "brew upgrade" from the terminal, before upgrading finished the battery ran out on my MBP and the computer restarted. Now when I go to open a terminal the terminal window flashes up for a split second before closing. I managed to capture the terminal output before it closed:

[image]

dyld: Library not loaded: /use/local/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib

How can I fix this?

Please note that I cannot open a terminal to issue any commands!

Comment: How did you set your shell to zsh ? The obvious way is restore the dylib from a backup

Comment: With chsh command. Any idea how I can open a bash shell?

Comment: How did you recover from the brew upgrade?

Comment: @PetrusTheron opened a bash shell and ran brew upgrade fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [iTerm.app](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) You can set up a profile that you can set the start up program do be /bin/bash

Or create a new admin user and use that to restore or reinstall files. I think you might be able to use dscl from that user to change the original users' shell

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the advice given would work. What I did though was right click terminal "New Command"... "bash", and was able to open a bash shell to fix this.

Comment: Awesome @stur - feel free to edit or make your own answer. Any time you can solve things without needing additional software, the better. Also, once bash was running, did `brew update` suffice to correct whatever caused zsh to fail to complete the launch process.

Comment: @bmike - yes brew upgrade fixed the missing dylib file, and I was able to restart the terminal into a zsh shell afterward. Thanks for your help.

Comment: StuR, I have similar problem, i cannot run terminal or iterm because it fails to open bash. i could try another shell. However when I right-click terminal, i do not see a "New Command" option. ???

Comment: I managed to execute the command /usr/local/bin/brew update, from Automator execute shell script and using /bin/csh shell. let's see if it works.